# Resource defines an update using PATCH but app wants POST in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm trying to add edit functionality to my web app, and am having some trouble. The error page I get back when I try to complete an edit of my Request object indicates that it couldn't find the right route, but the same error page contains a list of routes which includes the route it's looking for. So I'm a bit flummoxed.

The "new" method is almost identical to this edit method and the pages are almost identical as well.

The error page begins **No route matches [POST] "/requests/19/edit"** and then, partway down the route listing, I see this:

```
requests_path   GET /requests(.:format) requests#index
POST    /requests(.:format) requests#create
new_request_path    GET /requests/new(.:format) requests#new
edit_request_path   GET /requests/:id/edit(.:format)    requests#edit
request_path    GET /requests/:id(.:format) requests#show
PATCH   /requests/:id(.:format) requests#update
PUT /requests/:id(.:format) requests#update
DELETE  /requests/:id(.:format) requests#destroy
```

So Rails seems to be generating a request_path which expects a PATCH, not a POST, right?

routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do    
  root "pages#index"    
  resources :destinations    
  resources :users
  resources :manifests    
  resources :requests 
  :
```

request.rb

```
class Request < ActiveRecord::Base    
  validates_presence_of :justification
  validates_presence_of :required_by    
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :manifest
  belongs_to :network
  has_many :uploaded_files    
  scope :sorted, lambda{ order("required_by") }    
end
```

edit.html.rb

```
<% @page_title = "Update Request" %>
<%= link_to("<< Back to List", {:action => 'index'}, :class => 'back-link') %>
<div class="requests edit">
  <h2>Update Request</h2>
  <%= form_for :request, url: request_path(@request) do |f| %>
    <%= render(:partial => "form", :locals => {:f => f}) %> 
    <div class="form-buttons">
      <%= submit_tag("Update Request") %>
    </div>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

requests_controller.rb

```
  def update
    @request = Request.find(params[:id])
    p = {'file' => params[:request][:uploaded_file], 'request_id' => @request.id}
    uf = UploadedFile.create(p)
    if @request.update_attributes(request_params)
      flash[:notice] = "Request updatred succesfully"
      redirect_to :action => 'show', :id => @request.id
    else
      render 'edit'
    end
  end
```

What have I missed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
<%= form_for :request, url: request_path(@request) do |f| %>
```

to

```
<%= form_for :request, url: request_path(@request), method: :patch do |f| %>
```

in your `edit.html.erb`

`form_for`(as you are using it) sets ***POST*** as ***default HTTP verb***. You need to alter it by setting `method :patch` which responds to the update action.

You can simplify it to just

```
<%= form_for @request do |f| %>
```

Check the [***APIdoc***](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper/form_for) for more Info.

Comment: Well, dang. That was easy. Is this expected behavior or should Rails be smart enough to know what the resource route it created is expecting? It seems like an internal inconsistency (which is not a complaint, just a question).

Comment: @Bret `form_for` by default do `POST`, if  `request` is a new record, otherwise `PATCH` when `request` is already persisted.

Comment: Hmmm. I would have expected this to work that way then, since request _had_ already been persisted and was just being updated.

Comment: @Bret I've updated my answer to provide bit more info :)

Comment: I think I get it now. Thanks, Pavan and Arup!